# Why does my Moto X phone support mDNS but my Samsung Tablet does not?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, dns

I have a device that is broadcasting mDNS, I am using this app to view it in the Bonjour Browser:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.he.networktools&hl=en

On my Samsung Tablet, it cannot find my device.
On my Moto X, the device comes up in the bonjour browser list.

Why does my device show up on the bonjour browser of my Moto X and not my Samsung Tablet? (and how do I fix it?????)

My Samsung tablet cannot detect mDNS packets. I tried the code here and it failed on my Tablet but worked fine on my MotoX. http://cafbit.com/entry/testing_multicast_support_on_android

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the second sentence you say "On my Samsung Tablet, it cannot find my device". and then you ask "Why does my device show up on the bonjour browser of my Samsung Tablet and not my Moto X? ". Whether you have problem in Moto x or your Samsung Tablet?

Comment: I fixed the text

Answer (score 1):

The standard Android distribution (as of version 6.0) doesn’t support mDNS resolution nor announce it’s device name on mDNS yet. So it’s up the device manufacturer to add support.

*I’ll investigate how much effort it would be to write a mDNS client for Android to announce a device name. Shouldn’t be too complicated, though mDNS resolution wouldn’t be possible for an app at the current API limitations.*